# Finding different Ids with the same value in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following data in pandas dataframe.

```
    Id1  StartTime               start_lat   start_long StartGeohash
0   113 2016-11-01 10:50:28.063 -33.139507  -100.226715 9vbsx2
1   113 2016-11-02 10:49:24.063 -33.139507  -100.226715 9vbsx2
2   115 2016-11-03 10:55:20.063 -36.197660  -101.186050 9y2jcm
3   115 2016-11-04 10:53:19.063 -36.197660  -101.186050 9y2jcm
4   116 2016-11-01 12:59:21.127 -33.139507  -100.226715 9vbsx2
5   114 2016-11-02 12:41:46.063 -36.197660  -101.186050 9y2jcm
6   120 2016-11-03 12:48:04.063 -36.197660  -101.186050 9y2jcm
7   117 2016-11-04 12:51:51.063 -36.197660  -101.186050 9y2jck
8   118 2016-11-05 18:07:01.063 -36.197660  -101.186050 9y2jck
```

I am trying to find out how many different Id1's have the same StartGeohash

```
    StartGeohash       Count
    9vbsx2             2
    9y2jcm             3
    9y2jck             2
```

I tried with the following but it yields the different StartGeohashes for every Id1

```
  group = df1.groupby('Id1')['StartGeohash'].unique()
```

Any advice would be really helpful. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
df1.groupby('StartGeohash').apply(lambda x: len(x.Id1.drop_duplicates()))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [nunique](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html)

```
 df.groupby(['StartGeohash'])['Id1'].nunique()
```

output

```
StartGeohash
9vbsx2    2
9y2jck    2
9y2jcm    3
```

Comment: So by using `['Id1']` you select the respective columns in all groups?

Comment: @ Arco Bast - Yes, groupby returns all the columns, then select the desired column and use nunique() to get distinct

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the `'StartGeohash'` column, I use the `duplicated` method to slice the column and count unique values with `nunique`

```
df.StartGeohash[df.StartGeohash.duplicated()].nunique()

3
```